# matlab neural network custom weights initialization

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to learn how to use the neural networks in matlab, but I'm having some trouble understanding how they work.

I want to build a MultiLayerPerceptron.

I started with:

```
netconf = [10];
net = feedforwardnet(netconf);
```

I've seen that `feedforwardnet` accepts as first parameter the hiddenSizes, so I don't specify how many neurons I want on the input layer and the output layer.

1. My first question is: the number of neurons on the input layer and the output layer are learnd implicitely from the input size and the output size? Or I need to specify them explicitely elsewhere?

Now, let's move on the main question: I want to initialize the weights and biases in a custom way, I've seen that `feedforwardnet` is a `network` object, and that to do what I want to do, I need to touch the `net.initFcn` but how?

I've already written the function that should generate the weights and biases (simple gaussian weights and biases):

```
function weights = randomNormalWeights(sz, mean, std)
weights = mean + randn(sz) * std;
end
```

But how can I specify that I want my function to be called every time I generate new weights and biases?